# How to join two vector<vector<string>> in c++ based on a common column

Tags: c++, vector, inner-join

So what I want to do is essentially do an inner join of two tables in c++. However, the only guide I could is this one from geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-tables-using-multimaps/

An example below is as follows:

```
// First Column Name: Numbers
// Second Column Name: Alphabets
vector<vector<string>> v1 = { vector<string> { "Numbers", "Alphabets" }
                              vector<string> { "1", "a" },
                              vector<string> { "2", "b" },
                              vector<string> { "3", "a" } }

// First Column Name: Fruits
// Second Column Name: Alphabets
vector<vector<string>> v2 = { vector<string> { "Fruits", "Alphabets" }
                              vector<string> { "apple", "a" },
                              vector<string> { "pear", "a" },
                              vector<string> { "peach", "c" },
                              vector<string> { "orange", "b" } }
```

So if I want to do a inner join via alphabets, (like the solution in the link, I can pass two arguments which is the index of the columns I want to compare) and get the following output:

```
vector<vector<string>> result = { vector<string> { "Numbers", "Alphabets", "Fruits" }
                                  vector<string> { "1", "a", "apple" },
                                  vector<string> { "1", "a", "pear" },
                                  vector<string> { "3", "a", "apple" } 
                                  vector<string> { "3", "a", "pear" }, 
                                  vector<string> { "2", "b", "orange" }, }
```

As you can see, I currently also need the column names in the final table, in the sense that I need to know that column 1 refers to Numbers, column 2 is Alphabets, and column 3 is Fruits, as I would need to extract out the data in a specific column later in my code, kind of like a SQL "get Numbers from result" which I can easily do with a for loop.

How do I do so? I've been stuck on this since I'm sure when building the new table, I would need to omit the first row of headers for both table when doing the comparison etc, which makes things complicated if there a strings of the same value.

EDIT: My data does not necessarily have to be in that format of vector<vector>. How I do it is I have an API that gives me a vector once I pass it my column Name, so I can easily store this in an unordered_map as well. I modeled into a "table-like" structure after that solution.

My original code looked something like this:

```
joinTwoTable(vector<vector<string>>& v1, int columnIndex1, 
             vector<vector<string>>& v2, int columnIndex2) 
{
    vector<vector<string>> result;
    vector<string> header;
    
    // Add in the header_row
    for (string s : v1[0]) {
        current.push_back(s);
    }
    
    for (string s2 : v2[0]) {
        // Skip the common column again
        if (s2 == v2[0][columnIndex2]) {
            continue;
        }
        current.push_back(s2);
    }
    
    for (vector<string> v : v1) {
        for (vector<string> v2 : v2) {
            if (v[columnIndex1] == v2[columnIndex2]) {
                vector<string> current;
                
                for (string s : v) {
                    current.push_back(s);
                }
                
                for (string s2 : v2) {
                    // Skip the common column again
                    if (s2 == v2[columnIndex2]) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    current.push_back(s2);
                }
                result.push_back(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the issue is also because here I can only inner join on one column, but what if I need to inner join on every common column names?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Better don't trust anything from that gfg site.

Comment: please show what you tried. Your approach is probably much different from how I or others would approach it, hence problems that seem obvious to you arent really obvious. Please post your code

Comment: how did the data end up in a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` in the first place? Some kind of map seems much more appropriate

Comment: PS, I modeled my data after that solution, but my data can essentially utilize an `unordered_map` as well, since in my code, I know what my header is, and I can add the individual values in as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are actually computing for the column header names two times. First you are pushing them manually, then in the main loop you have `for (vector<string> v : v1)` which actually will start from the first row, which is again those column names.

Instead you can use a normal for loop and start from the second row.

Another problem is here

```
for (string s2 : v2) {
                    // Skip the common column again
                    if (s2 == v2[columnIndex2]) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    current.push_back(s2);
                }
```

Here you are assuming that no other row item has the same string value as the row item of common column, which is not a good assumption at all. This worked in case of headings as column names have to be unique in SQL.

Here is my try

```
joinTwoTable(vector<vector<string>>& v1, int columnIndex1, vector<vector<string>>& v2, int columnIndex2) 
{
    vector<vector<string>> result;
    vector<string> columns;

    string commonColumn = v1[0][columnIndex1];

    for(string s: v1[0]) {
        columns.push_back(s);
    }
    for(string s: v2[0]) {
        if(s == commonColumn) continue;
        columns.push_back(s);
    }

    // push headers
    result.push_back(columns);

    for(int i=1; i!=v1.size(); i++) {

        string joiner = v1[i][columnIndex1];

        for(int j=1; j!=v2.size(); j++) {
            if(v2[j][columnIndex2] == joiner) {

                // push a new joined row
                vector<string> temp;

                for(string s1: v1[i]) {
                    temp.push_back(s1);
                }
                for(auto k=0; k!=v2[j].size(); k++) {
                    if(k==columnIndex2) continue;
                    temp.push_back(v2[j][k]);
                }

                result.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```